# Problem connecting Pi 2 to laptop display

Tags: raspbian

I want to connect a Pi 2 to a my laptop's display. I have already tried to connect using PuTTy. But I can't get the IP address of the Pi.

How do I find the IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Steps to connect:

1. Connect your Raspberry Pi to the same WiFi as your computer.
2. Open Raspberry Pi preferences

[image: Preferences]

3. Enable SSH (don't worry about serial)

[image: Enable SSH]

4. Open up a terminal and type `hostname -I`
5. Log into your Pi from your laptop with the default username 'pi' and password 'raspberry'

[image: Putty config]

More information can be found on the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/windows.md).

Answer (score 1):

What operating system is your laptop running ? How are you connecting your Pi to the laptop ?

I connect to my Pi's on my local network via wifi and use an app called LanScan on my Apple MacBook to discover their ip addresses. If you have a screen and keyboard attached to your Pi you can type 'ifconfig' in a terminal window to find the ipaddress.